# apex string split

Tags: apex, array, split

Unable to split string by multiple characters.

```
String myString = 'abc$$$xyz';
string[] myArray = myString.Split('$$$');
System.Debug(myArray.Size());
```

I get result for myArray.Size = 1 and when myArray = 'abc$$$xyz'

Please shed some light

Answer (score 3):

String.split() expects a regular expression, not a string.

Use

```
myString.Split('\\$\\$\\$');
```

(Thanks to @Mugambo)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_split